# Is it good practise to break your site down into multiple files, rather than coding it on one html page?

Tags: html, single-page-application

So I'm just starting web programming and design, and I have learned the basics of html and css and am now trying to learn javascript php ajax and so on. I have an idea for a website but I would like to avoid having to reload everything whenever a link is clicked so I have linked my files for menus, sub menus and content to external php files using javascript. Is this in fact good practise to, or are there any glaring downsides i.e too many server requests or something else I am not seeing.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like there are some gaps in your understanding. You should look into the technique called "Single page application" or SPA which allows you to build a website which looks like it's just 1 page but is actually several "pages" split out as templates and navigated by javascript. Rendering in SPAs is done on the client using javascript which fetches a template and data from the web server before combining them. There are many tools available to build SPAs including javascript frameworks (ember, angular, react) js task runners (grunt, gulp) package managers (npm, bower) templating tools (yo)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its good to have modular approach for constructing any web application. I think you should separate out front-end and back-end things. This will also helps you to develop your application fast if you have a team.  As @Cameron said you should also consider SPA.